# Htaccess redirect domain to subdomain with variables

Tags: .htaccess, variables, redirect

Just trying to make requests like

http://www.mysite.com/dir/index.php?id=123

go to

http://orginal.mysite.com/dir/index.php?id=123

because my site is having a total make-over and 
I'd like links from google to go to the archived original.mysite.com

It must be simple to do but I can't figure it out even after an hour of searching (here & google) and trying different things.

Comment: It would probably be better to have `http://dev.mysite.com` as your new, development server, and leave `http://mysite.com` as the front facing site.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.mysite.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^dir/index.php$ http://orginal.mysite.com/dir/index.php [QSA,L,R=301]
```

This will redirect anything going to www.mysite.com, with URI `/dir/index.php` with ANY query string, to original.mysite.com with the same URI and query string.